# How to dump PGresult

Tags: c, postgresql, libpq

I am trying to debug my C program that accesses a postgres database.

I would like to dump the contents of PGresult using some postgres provided routine.

Is there a postgres provided routine that will dump PGresult in a human readable way?

I will add that as an option to the logging that will dump the contents of PGresult.

Here is a related question for non-SELECT commands:
[How to dump PGresult for non-SELECT commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33028940/how-to-dump-pgresult-for-nonselect-commands)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `src/interfaces/libpq/fe-print.c` there is a public function `PQprint`; it's [in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-exec.html).