# How to dump PGresult for non-SELECT commands

Tags: c, postgresql

I am trying to debug my C program that accesses a postgres database.

I would like to dump the contents of PGresult using some postgres provided routine, where the PGresult is from a command that is not a SELECT.

Is there a postgres provided routine that will dump PGresult in a human readable way?

I will add that as an option to the logging that will dump the contents of PGresult.

I previously asked this question:
[How to dump PGresult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32213441/how-to-dump-pgresult)
and the answer is good for SELECTs, but it is not good for other commands.

[edit] I am looking to dump it for debugging purposes.  So, if I set logging to debug level, I would like to see whatever information is in PGreturn.  I am hoping there is some function that will do this.  I also hope it trims out information that is not relevant.  I have not looked at the Postgres source code to see what is available.

Comment: What sort of output are you looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the function

```
char *PQresultErrorField(const PGresult *res, int fieldcode);
```

you can get various information on the status of the performed operation, including severity, sqlstate, main and detail error messages, hint message and several others. See details in [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-exec.html).